# Batch Inserts with NHiberbnate, Oracle and Fluent NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, bulkinsert

EDIT:

I'm using Fluent NHibernate, NHibernate with an Oracle DB
So the test I'm conducting is as follows:

```
    [Test]
    public void CanIInsertLargeVolumesOfDataToOracleInUnder5Mins()
    {
        var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();
        var entities = GetEntities();

        using (var session = UnitOfStatelessWork.GetUnderlyingSession())
        {
            using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted))
            {
                foreach (var entity in entities.Select(entity => new EntityObject(entity) {SomeProperty = 19675464.25M}))
                {
                    session.Insert(entity);
                }

                transaction.Commit();
            }
        }

        stopwatch.Stop();
        var time = stopwatch.Elapsed;
        Assert.IsTrue(time < TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5.0));
    }
```

My connection string looks like the following:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add connectionString="Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=myhost)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=some.service.com)));User ID=user;Password=user" name="OracleConnection" providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I have the following fluent configurations, for SQL Server:

```
var fluentConfiguration = Fluently
            .Configure()
            .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2005.ConnectionString(c => c.Is(connStr)))
            .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(mappingAssembly));
        fluentConfiguration.ExposeConfiguration(f =>
                                                    {
                                                        f.SetProperty("generate_statistics", "false");
                                                        f.SetProperty("command_timeout", "60");
                                                        f.SetListener(ListenerType.PreInsert, new AuditEventListener());
                                                        f.SetListener(ListenerType.PreUpdate, new AuditEventListener());
                                                        f.SetProperty("adonet.batch_size", "1");
                                                        f.SetProperty("hibernate.order_inserts", "true");
                                                        f.SetProperty("hibernate.order_updates", "true");
                                                    });
```

Then for Oracle:

```
var fluentConfiguration = Fluently
            .Configure()
            .Database(OracleClientConfiguration.Oracle10.AdoNetBatchSize(1000).ConnectionString(c => c.Is(connStr)))
            .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(mappingAssembly));
        fluentConfiguration.ExposeConfiguration(f =>
                                                    {
                                                        f.SetProperty("generate_statistics", "false");
                                                        f.SetProperty("command_timeout", "60");
                                                        f.SetProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "NHibernate.Driver.OracleDataClientDriver");
                                                        f.SetListener(ListenerType.PreInsert, new AuditEventListener());
                                                        f.SetListener(ListenerType.PreUpdate, new AuditEventListener());
                                                        f.SetProperty("hibernate.order_inserts", "true");
                                                        f.SetProperty("hibernate.order_updates", "true");
                                                    });
```

I'm then using Stateless Sessions and batching for both databases and can insert 750000 records to the SQL DB in approx. 100 seconds.

In Oracle, the same test takes about 12 minutes.

Anyone see any gaping errors that I'm not seeing?

Comment: So it looks like NHibernate is just not the one when it comes to fast data insertion in Oracle... Ended up using ODP.NET and array binding... 750000 records inserted in approx. 50 seconds. Sorted!

Answer (score 0):

- Stateless sessions do not use batching
- You are overriding the batch size when you `SetProperty("adonet.batch_size", "1")`

So batching has nothing to do with it. We don't have enough information about how your code is doing the inserts to help you further.

My suggestion is that you use a .net profiler to determine where the time is being spent.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So I'll put that down to eager-editing, I actually removed the line to `SetProperty("adonet.batch_size", "1")` after posting the question, removed from post now. With regards to stateless sessions and batching, I was profiling with NHProf and I'm sure batching does work with Stateless Sessions, BUT, I could be wrong, I was in the lab so to speak in the small hours, so it may have been a normal session. Still the performance diffence is quite significant, there must be something wrong here?

Comment: ...That's eager editing by me by the way, just to avoid confusion!